# Toggle Text from asterisk to Normal text

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering is it possible to have text starting out as `******` and when they click the eye it goes to `123456`?

the number that I want to show/hide is in MySQL, and also what they use to reset their password, so would it also be possible to hide it after like 5-10 seconds.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an input field, this is a very quick outline of what you could do:

```js
var resetCode = document.getElementById('resetCode');
var showCode = document.getElementById('showCode');

showCode.addEventListener('click', showHiddenText, false);

function showHiddenText (e) {
  var _hidden = resetCode.getAttribute('data-hidden');

  // check if the text is hidden so we're not triggering multiple timers
  if (!!_hidden) {
    resetCode.setAttribute('data-hidden', 'false');
    resetCode.textContent = resetCode.getAttribute('data-value');

    // reset the display after an arbitrary amount of time
    setTimeout(function () {
      resetCode.setAttribute('data-hidden', 'true');
      resetCode.textContent = "******"
    }, 5000);

  }

}
```

```html
<!-- data-hidden would be set by default -->
<!-- data-value would be obtained from the server via ajax or templating engine -->
<span id="resetCode" data-hidden="true" data-value="724814">******</span>
<button id="showCode">Show Code</button>
```

### Edit

In light of your comment, here's an update:

```js
var _timer;
var resetCode = document.getElementById('resetCode');
var showCode = document.getElementById('showCode');
var hideCode = document.getElementById('hideCode');

showCode.addEventListener('click', clickShow, false);
hideCode.addEventListener('click', clickHide, false);

function clickHide () {

  var _hidden = resetCode.getAttribute('data-hidden');

  if (!!_hidden) {
    hideTheThings();
    clearTimeout(_timer);
  }

}


function clickShow () {
  var _hidden = resetCode.getAttribute('data-hidden');

  if (!!_hidden) {
    showTheThings();
    _timer = setTimeout(hideTheThings, 5000);
  }

}

function showTheThings () { 
  hideCode.classList.remove('hidden');
  showCode.classList.add('hidden');
  resetCode.setAttribute('data-hidden', 'false');
  resetCode.textContent = resetCode.getAttribute('data-value');
}

function hideTheThings () {
  hideCode.classList.add('hidden');
  showCode.classList.remove('hidden');
  resetCode.setAttribute('data-hidden', 'true');
  resetCode.textContent = "******";

}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<!-- data-hidden would be set by default -->
<!-- data-value would be obtained from the server via ajax or templating engine -->
<span id="resetCode" data-hidden="true" data-value="724814">******</span>
<button id="showCode">Show Code</button>
<button id="hideCode" class="hidden">Hide Code</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, is it possible to also make the "Show Code" turn into a Hide Code?
Sorry in advance for being a Pain

Comment: Hi. Updated. It can be done more efficiently for sure but consider this a very rough demonstration of how it can be done.

Comment: Hi, Really Appreciate the help! it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: @Mad_Tom05 Welcome to StackOverflow btw. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="password">` and change the type to `"text"` to show the characters visibly.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(input.type === 'password') input.type = 'text';
    else input.type = 'password';
});
```

```html
<input type="password" value="123456"> 
<button>
Toggle
</button>
```

Comment: Ahh okay, i was just hoping it didn't have to be an input, Thanks! ill try that.